# Python: How to use Value and Array in Multiprocessing pool

Tags: python, arrays, multiprocessing, pool

For `multiprocessing` with `Process`, I can use `Value, Array` by setting `args` param.

With `multiprocessing` with `Pool`, how can I use `Value, Array.` There is nothing in the docs on how to do this.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Array

def f(n, a):
    n.value = 3.1415927
    for i in range(len(a)):
        a[i] = -a[i]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num = Value('d', 0.0)
    arr = Array('i', range(10))

    p = Process(target=f, args=(num, arr))
    p.start()
    p.join()

    print(num.value)
    print(arr[:])
```

I am trying to use `Value, Array` within the code snippet below.

```
import multiprocessing


def do_calc(data):
    #  access num or 
    #  work to update arr
    newdata =data * 2
    return newdata

def start_process():
    print 'Starting', multiprocessing.current_process().name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num             = Value('d', 0.0)
    arr             = Array('i', range(10))  
    inputs          = list(range(10))
    print 'Input   :', inputs

    pool_size       = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2
    pool            = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=pool_size,initializer=start_process, )
    pool_outputs    = pool.map(do_calc, inputs)
    pool.close() # no more tasks
    pool.join()  # wrap up current tasks

    print 'Pool    :', pool_outputs
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I never knew "the reason" for this, but `multiprocessing` (`mp`) uses different pickler/unpickler mechanisms for functions passed to most `Pool` methods.  It's a consequence that objects created by things like `mp.Value`, `mp.Array`, `mp.Lock`, ..., can't be passed as arguments to such methods, although they *can* be passed as arguments to `mp.Process` *and* to the optional `initializer` function of `mp.Pool()`.  Because of the latter, this works:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def init(aa, vv):
    global a, v
    a = aa
    v = vv

def worker(i):
    a[i] = v.value * i

if __name__ == "__main__":
    N = 10
    a = mp.Array('i', [0]*N)
    v = mp.Value('i', 3)
    p = mp.Pool(initializer=init, initargs=(a, v))
    p.map(worker, range(N))
    print(a[:])
```

and that prints

```
[0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27]
```

That's the only way I know of to get this to work across platforms.

On Linux-y platforms (where `mp` creates new processes via `fork()`), you can instead create your `mp.Array` and `mp.Value` (etc) objects as module globals any time *before* you do `mp.Pool()`.  Processes created by `fork()` inherit whatever is in the module global address space at the time `mp.Pool()` executes.

But that doesn't work at all on platforms (read "Windows") that don't support `fork()`.

Comment: If your original question was answered, you should accept the answer, and open new issues for new questions.  Otherwise posts become an incomprehensible mess of endless, unrelated comments.