# How to share the memory with multiprocessing.Pool's workers, without using global variables?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

There are two functions:

```
def tibidam(..., foo_dyn, index):
    print("(" + str(index) + ") B:", foo_dyn)

    for i in range(...):
        for j ...
            if j not in foo_dyn:
                foo_dyn[ep] = j

    print("(" + str(index) + ") A:", foo_dyn)

def tata(..., foo):
    foo_dyn = Array('i', len(foo))
    
    foo_dyn = foo

    with Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        pool.starmap(tibidam, [(..., foo_dyn, i) 
            for i in range(4)])
    
    return foo
```

Output (formatted):

```
foo  : [0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  10, 11]
(0) B: [0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  10, 11]
(1) B: [0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  10, 11]
(2) B: [0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  10, 11]
(3) B: [0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  10, 11]
(0) A: [27, 1,  2,  3,  64, 5,  6,  7,  80, 9,  10, 11]
(2) A: [0,  1,  64, 3,  4,  5,  13, 7,  8,  9,  92, 11]
(3) A: [0,  1,  2,  31, 4,  5,  6,  73, 8,  9,  10, 18]
(1) A: [0,  18, 2,  3,  4,  27, 6,  7,  8,  99, 10, 11]
...
```

Expected output (formatted):

```
foo  : [0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  10, 11]
(0) B: [0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  10, 11]
(1) B: [0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  10, 11]
(2) B: [0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  10, 11]
(3) B: [0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  10, 11]
(0) A: [27, 1,  2,  3,  64, 5,  6,  7,  80, 9,  10, 11]
(2) A: [27, 1,  55, 3,  64, 5,  13, 7,  80, 9,  92, 11]
(3) A: [27, 1,  55, 31, 64, 5,  13, 73, 80, 9,  92, 18]
(1) A: [27, 87, 55, 31, 64, 88, 13, 73, 80, 99, 92, 18]
...
```

How I can change `foo_dyn` in all workers, whenever `foo_dyn` changes? It seems, that `pool.starmap(...)` creates a copy of the `foo_dyn`, for each process... No, I want pass `foo_dyn` to the pool only once. But, again, without using global variables, at all.

AFAIK, `multiprocessing.Pool` supports `initializer` and `initargs` arguments: I can write own initializer:

```
_init(foo):
    global foo_dyn

    foo_dyn = foo
```

, but it uses global variable `foo_dyn` (by the way, using `_init` function doesn't solve the problem). In passing, I saw a few questions, with almost the same trouble. However, all solutions were associated with using global variables.

Comment: Shared memory : multiprocessing module provides Array and Value objects to share data between processes.

    Array: a ctypes array allocated from shared memory.
    Value: a ctypes object allocated from shared memory.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html#multiprocessing.shared_memory.SharedMemory

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes

Comment: Oh, @Joe, thanks you! :) I've seen that, but I'm more interested in a solution compatible with older Python versions. For example, it can be implemented with using multiprocessing.Process class. But, due to inefficiency, for my case, of this approach, I want use multiprocessing.Pool class (without using global variables).

Comment: `Value` and `Array` are available in 2.7 https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39322677/python-how-to-use-value-and-array-in-multiprocessing-pool

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675766/combine-pool-map-with-shared-memory-array-in-python-multiprocessing

Comment: @Joe, please, stop... Re-read my question.

Comment: @MaximTemny: Can’t you pass objects of the `multiprocessing` types as function arguments?

Comment: @DavisHerring, what do you mean? I pass `foo_dyn` (`multiprocessing.Array`) to `tibidam(...)`.

Comment: @MaximTemny: Sorry, I phrased that very poorly.  I mean to say that it *should* work to pass such objects, and you should phrase your question as “Why isn’t this working?” with the usual complete reproducer.  (For example, your code shows `foo_dyn` being reassigned to be just `foo`, which is surely wrong.)

Comment: @DavisHerring, oh, exactly... Didn't pay attention to it... But, differently, using `multiprocessing.Array`, I couldn't assign `foo` to `foo_dyn`, because it... Well, thank you. :>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, without using the global variables:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager

def tibidam(..., foo_dyn, index):
    for i in range(...):
        for j ...
            if j not in foo_dyn:
                foo_dyn[ep] = j

def tata(..., foo):
    foo_dyn = Manager().list(foo)

    with Pool(processes=4) as pool:
        pool.starmap(tibidam, [(..., foo_dyn, i)
            for i in range(4)])

    return foo_dyn
```

Thank you all! :>